# Websphere Liberty Support for Work Manager

Tags: websphere-liberty

I am migrating application from WebSphere to liberty. It uses WebSphere work managers.

What is the use of work manager? Is this supported in liberty. What is the alternative in liberty

Answer (score 1):

I would refer to the [JavaDoc](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/asynchbeans/WorkManager.html) for details regarding work manager, but in short

> The WorkManager is the abstraction for dispatching and monitoring asynchronous work and is a factory for asynchronous beans.

WorkManager is not part of WebSphere Liberty, but you can largely recreate the functionality in Liberty by configuring a concurrencyPolicy for its managed executors.  You can find more information on that [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.doc/ae/rwlp_mig_workmgr.html)

I would also recommend looking into the [WebSphere Application Server Migration Toolkit](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Application_Server_Migration_Toolkit) as it might help you with the migration process.  You can check out an example [here](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/move-applications-liberty-using-migration-toolkit/).

Comment: I have used the toolkit and one of the suggestions is that WorkManager is not supported in liberty. So was looking for the alternative

Comment: Use the concurrency utilities for java EE API. The concurrent-1.0 feature enables it. The API is essentially the JVM ExecutorService, but you can get application context on the extra thread

Answer (score 0):

The detailed help for the migration toolkit WorkManager rule recommends the concurrency utilities and gives several links to information including the one provided above. I am wondering if you are not seeing the detailed help when you use the tool? If you are using the Eclipse tool, open the help view (Window > Show view > Help), select the analysis result, and then click on Detailed help.  If  you are using the binary scanner, you can view the help directly from the HTML report.  When I looked at the help file, I see that one of the links is broke, and I will open an issue for this.  [This article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_migrate_to_eeconcurrency.html) gives lots of examples on how to migrate to the concurrency utilities.